# SQL- Selecting NULL columns only

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I need to write a query which will look at a table, and select from it any/all columns(s) that have ALL NULL rows.

I would prefer to not have to say "SELECT (each column name)", but would rather say "SELECT (from whole table, those columns) WHERE (rows are all NULL).

I know about CASE and WHEN statements, but my understanding is that columns must be specifically referenced in the select statement. I'll be using this query on many different tables, with many different dimensions and column names, so I would like the query to be versatile.

I'm using SQL in Toad with a Vertica db.

This is what my tables look similar to:

[image: TABLE_with_null]

This table contains the columns i need the query.  The columns i need to query are such as "owner_id", NOT TYPE_NAME, NULLABLE, etc.  Each row in THIS table, is actually a column with such and such many values, and it is these values I need to run my query against.

'Simply' put: If a column has ALL NULL rows, I need to identify and/or select it.

Any Suggestions? %Solved^^^%

I found this example of a way to loop through columns, but despite my research, I'm still having trouble making sense of it all.

Such as: how is col_names difference from column_name?  Same for the text in the FROM statement and WHERE. Should those not both the table name? Then what does the found_rows() signify?

```
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;

select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

SET i = 1;
the_loop: LOOP

   IF i > num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH col_names 
    INTO col_name;     

     //do stuff

    SET i = i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: You've really got tables which contain rows where every single column is null? So there's no primary key on the table?

Comment: In the provided image an example would be "remarks" (all null values in the column). Given that what would you need to get? All non-null columns?

Comment: @apokryfos I need that column returned, so I can note which columns from which tables in the db have all NULL values.  Again, the idea is that i want to be able to run a query that will check and identify for me any columns which are all NULL, without having to manually go and look into the tables and scroll through to see all NULLs.

Comment: The 'easiest' way to do this is to use the 'information_schema' tables (metadata)  and get a list of nullable columns for the table and then generate the query as text  and run it. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html. see .'dynamic queries' You can do it all in the database. However, , imo, it is easier to use a scripting language.

Comment: The most practical thing I can think of is create a procedure with a loop (example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) and use the column names as suggested by @RyanVincent . I personally am very hopeless in doing these things so this is all I can do.

Comment: @RyanVincent Sure, let me try to clarify more.  
   Upon further investigation of my database, I found that from the above pic,  'owner_id' (for instance)  is actually a column in itself.  The pic shows a tables of COLUMNS (as rows for some reason),  where the  pic table columns describe the characteristics of actual columns (owner_id). So owner_id is an ACTUAL column, and others like it are those that I need to run the query through.
What I need to do is run a query through this whole table above (owner_id, is_deleted_flag, etc.) and return those columns ONLY which are ALL NULL values.

Comment: @RyanVincent I was considering trying some query such as SELECT COUNT(column), this should give me the number of rows in the entire column.  
  Then I run SELECT COUNT(column) WHERE (SELECT column WHERE column IS NULL)
  If these two numbers are the same then I know the entire column is full of NULL rows.  However, this may be a very roundabout method and still requires me to select each column individually.

Comment: That makes sense. So you want the count of total rows in the table. And, a count of not null values in each column in that table. Then it is trivial to identify which columns have a zero count. Generating the queries to do that from the data-dictionary isn't difficult. You have to select each column individually which is why I suggest generating the queries programmatically

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, tbh.  Like i said, i'm running Toad, so the final queries will have to be done in there, but before I start taking server bandwidth I want to test these queries on a test db.

Comment: I would be using PHP to generate the mysql SQL query scripts that you would load and run however you wish. However, you need to be setup to run PHP. Whatever happens, it is an interesting problem and well worth asking. :)

Comment: Thanks all. I'll be looking at all these suggestions, especially the good ones from Diego and Ryan Vicent and comment back my results.  I appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to Identify which columns have NULL values on all rows and dont want to type all columns, right?

If thats so, this is how I would do:

1) Build a function that takes the  as an input parameter and does:
--FYI: this is a pseudo code. I dont have mysql here to get the correct syntax

```
select sum(
            case when CAST(<column_name> as varchar(5200)) is not null then 1 else 0 end --5200 seems to be your longer column
        )
from YOUR_TABLE
--the idea is to cast the column as anythig; if it is null, it gets a 0.
--If the sum across the rows is 0, it means that all the rows are null
```

2) Loop through the column names and call the function